# Deferred function resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

Here is my situation:

I have an "interface" that each of my controls use for basic things, one of those things is validation.

So I have a `processValidation` function which runs through each of the passed in functions for that particular control.  Those functions might be as simple as `isNumeric()` or more complex requiring a webservice call. These functions return a simple `boolean` stating whether or not this passed validation.

I need a generic way to have this call wait until that validation it is running finishes. I thought this was a perfect place for using Deferred methods, but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
            validator.validatorFn(value, $controlContainer);
        }).promise();

        $.when(dfd).done(function (result) {
            console.log('got here');
        });
```

When I get into the function being called I need a way to resolve the dfd. I guess that is my real problem.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**
I tried passing `dfd` to the validatorFn and resolving it there but the `$.when` never fires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure about your flow, but why not let `validator.validatorFn` return the deferred object? Something like:

```
validator.validatorFn = function(value, controlContainer) {
     var df = $.Deferred();
     // do validation
     // somewhere you call
     df.resolve(result);
     // or maybe df.reject(result);
     return df;
};
```

Then:

```
$.when(validator.validatorFn(value, controlContainer)).done(function (result) {
    console.log('got here');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6xt/)

Comment: This is actually perfect. I hadnt thought of that :) Thank you sir

Comment: @Mike: Welcome :) I know deferred objects can be tricky to understand (at least this was the case for me ;))

Comment: Well I thought I did understand them... Then this happened :)